# What are the WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID and GOOGLE_IOS_CLIENT_ID in the cordova gigya and cordova googleplus plugins

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4, google-plus, gigya

In the documentation for the Cordova Gigya plugin there is mention of the
GOOGLE_IOS_CLIENT_ID
and the
WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID

What exactly are they and where can you find them? 
Is it correct that the WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID is the id you can find at https://console.cloud.google.com/ ?

Also is there a way to get more (console) log detail out of the Gigya plugin?

Thanks

Comment: I hope this helps to you: https://javebratt.com/ionic-google-login/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need GOOGLE_IOS_CLIENT_ID and the WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID to enable Google login for all mobile CDC SDKs. Follow these instructions to create the credentials in the Google API console: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/415ba6c470b21014bbc5a10ce4041860.html

SAP CDC seems to have stopped supporting the Cordova SDK.

Comment: Both links are dead; however, content of the former is available at  https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/415ba6c470b21014bbc5a10ce4041860.html